# Non-vanishing section on compact manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Now if we have a compact smooth manifold M and a rank k vector bundle on it. Then I want to find a non-vanishing smooth section on M if $k>dim M$. But I have met some difficulties: The main idea is similar to the case when we proof the weak Whitney embedding theorem. Suppose
$\eta:M\rightarrow E$ Is the zero section, since M is compact, it is also an embedding, which we denote the submanifold by $S=\eta(M)$, then we want to show that there is section $\sigma:M\rightarrow E$, whose image intersects with S empty. It seems to me that the amount of this kind of $\sigma$ Is very large due to dimensional reasons, but I just don’t know how to extract one of them? How can I make it?

Comment: Hint: Use transversality theorem. When would a section of $E$ be transverse to the zero section?

Comment: Sorry, but I still cannot understand some details. If $dim E>2dim M$ then the two section can never intersect transversely, and what I need is to let them intersect emptily. What I need is to use the dimension trick here to construct a section by doing perturbation.

Comment: @XiuJiuCi That's the idea, yes. By transversality theorem there is a homotopy of $\sigma$ so that it makes $\sigma$, after the homotopy, transverse to the zero section. But that is possible iff they do not intersect, like you said. That gives a nowhere zero section (the subtlety here is to construct a homotopy of $\sigma$ *through sections of $E$* that makes it transverse to the zero section)

Comment: @Balarka Sen do you happen to know any reference for a full elementary proof? Atiyah says in a paper that this theorem is due to Serre, but that's in the context of algebraic varieties and uses homological algebra for the proof.

Comment: @BalarkaSen actually it appears that the necessary statement follows from Theorem 15.3 in Bredon's "Topology and Geometry". It states that any smooth map into the total space of a bundle allows for a section of said bundle that is transversal to the map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually feel that this is a very important structural theorem about vector bundles that is mysteriously hard to find in any introductory textbook.

The main theorem that I'll use can be found in Bredon's "Topology and Geometry" under number II.15.3:

> Let $E\overset{\pi}{\to}M$ be a smooth vector bundle over a smooth manifold $M$. Let $M'$ be a smooth manifold and $f:M'\to E$ a smooth map. Then there is a smooth section $\sigma:M\to E$ that can be chosen arbitrarily close to the zero section, such that $\sigma\pitchfork f$.

Here $\pitchfork$ denotes transversality of maps, i.e. the images of the differentials of the two maps sum up to the entire tangent space in the codomain at every point in the intersection of their images.

Now, if $E\overset{\pi}{\to}M^m$ has rank $k$ and $m=\mathrm{dim} M$, then we have three cases:

1. $k>m$. Then by the above theorem, there is a section $\sigma$ that is transverse to the zero section $E_0$, denoted $\sigma_0:M\to E$. By dimension counting, this implies that $\mathrm{im}(\sigma)\cap E_0=\varnothing$. Then, by induction, $E$ contains a rank $k-m$ trivial subbundle. For this reason, vector bundles of rank higher than the dimension of the base are not very interesting from the point of view of any classification of bundles (e.g. K-theory).
2. $k=m$. In this case the "generic" section of $E$ is transverse to the zero section and by dimension counting has only isolated zeros. This is the case e.g. for sections of tangent bundles, or complex line bundles over Riemann surfaces, and allows one to define the degree of a section.
3. $k<m$. In this case the "generic" section of $E$ is transverse to the zero section and turns to zero along a submanifold of $M$ of dimension $m-k$.

Comment: Observe that this follows without difficulty from the usual transversality theorem. Start with $0: M \to E$; there is a smooth homotopy $\sigma_t$ from $0$ to a map $\sigma: M \to E$ which is transverse to $f$, and in fact one may take $\sigma_t$ transverse to $f$ for all $t > 0$. Now the map $\pi \sigma_t: M \to M$ is a smooth homotopy starting at the identity; because diffeomorphisms form an open set in the $C^1$ topology, we see that $\pi \sigma_t$ is a diffeomorphism $g_t$ for small $t$, with $g_0$ the identity. Then the desired section is $\sigma_t g_t^{-1}: M \to E$, for small $t$.

Comment: @MikeMiller That's really neat, but why is is true that $\sigma_t$ can be made transverse for all $t>0$?

Comment: That's part of the transversality theorem itself when $M$ and $M'$ are compact (that's the implicit claim behind the statement that transverse maps form a dense open set). Any proof you've seen should include that. I missed that $M$ and $M'$ not compact; I never really internalized what versions of the transversality theorem are true in that case; in particular I never remember what topology to use on the function space. Anyway, the argument suffices for the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a differentiable metric and consider the sphere bundle associated, obstruction theory implies the existence of a section of the sphere bundle due to dimension.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obstruction_theory

Comment: This is *ridiculously* overkill.

Comment: The problem I have with obstruction theory is that: at least to my primary knowledge, what we have is "if such section exists, then some obstruction class must vanish". This kinda statement does not predict when such section does exist. To dig further, I have the impression that one has to look at its secondary, third, ... obstructions. But I have never learned how to compute those effectively. Would you mind giving a pointer to a good reference for that?